# cURL to PowerShell - Value in Square Bracket

Tags: powershell, curl

I've been struggling with another cURL to PowerShell conversion, specifically with a value in a square bracket.

Background: I am about 1,500 lines into a script that takes CSV import files, consumes it, validates it then converts it into a series of API calls, to automate a process which is done manually. I am doing this as a learning opportunity for myself, as I have never done API work before.

I have this cURL command (from Postman):

```
curl -X PATCH \
 https://example.com \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{
   "data": {
       "CID": 1234,
       "GroupId": [
           31
       ]
   }
}'
```

My struggle is with the square brackets round the "GroupId".

To convert it to PowerShell, I have done the following:

```
$URL = "https://example.com"
$Body = @{
    'data' = @{
        'CID'              = $CustomerID;
        'GroupId'          = $GetGroupID2
        }
}

$CurlArgument = '-X', 'PATCH',
'-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
$URL1,
'-H', 
$AuthBearer,
'--retry', '2',
'--retry-delay', '3',
'--retry-connrefused',
'-d', 
(($Body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"')

Write-Host "$Section cURL command took" ("{0:n1}" -f (Measure-Command {$PatchGroupResponse = & $CURLEXE @CurlArgument}).TotalSeconds) "Seconds"  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now, PowerShell "hates" the square brackets enclosing "GroupID", so I did the following (Let say $GetGroupID contains 31 (with no quotes. I get this earlier in my script and save it to the variable):

```
$GetGroupID2 = '['+$GetGroupID+']'
```

$GetGroupID2 now contains: [31], however when I ConvertTo-Json, I get the extra quotes round my $GetGroupID2, [31] becomes "[31]", I assume from the -replace command but I don't know why/how or how to stop it.

My @CurlArgument looks like this:

```
-X
PATCH
-H
Content-Type: application/json
https://example.com
-H
Authorization: Bearer 1234567890
--retry
2
--retry-delay
3
--retry-connrefused
-d
{
    \"data\":  {
                 \"CID\":  1234,
                 \"GroupId\":  \"[31]\"
             }
```

My call to the server is failing with:
{"Missing Argument, Argument Name = CID"}.

From what I can see, everything looks the same as my cURL command, except the extra quotes round my GroupID of "[31]" (should be [31]).

Can anyone give me any pointers as to why the extra quotes appear round the [31]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing this: `$GetGroupID2 = '['+$GetGroupID+']'` you are creating a string `[31]` and therefore the value gets quoted by the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet.

In fact, it should be output as the single element of an array, so if you do this instead:

```
'GroupId' = @($GetGroupID2)
```

you are forcing the `GroupId` value to be an array, so the output will be like this:

```
   "data": {
       "CID": 1234,
       "GroupId": [
           31
       ]
   }
```